# StimulSoft Report For ASP.NET MVC5.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stimulsoft

i'm new to ASP.NET MVC Razor. I want to install Stimulsoft Reports.Ultimate 2014.3 Retail on Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate with Update 4 
but dont add  toollbox.iam dont see in toolbox.iam add dll references 
 Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible to add MVC controls to toolbox in Visual Studio.